# Does the dojo dissapear when clan owner joins another clan?

Tags: warframe

Say that the owner of the clan is the only one active, and has this massive dojo that spent a very long time building it... Suddenly considers joining another clan.

What's gonna happen to its own dojo?

- Will it dissapear in thin air?
- Does title pass to the next member?
- What if there's no other member in it?
- What happens with all the resources used in the dojo, especially formas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the clan owner wants to leave, he must give up his title to a member of the clan before he can leave.

If the clan no longer has members then when the owner leaves, the dojo will be destroyed.